# General questions regarding Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

Im very new to Netlogo and trying to learn the basic. Therefore, I'm trying to extend an example code Netlogo provided. Im trying to make the pollution rate dependent upon the number of people from the Urban Site Pollution example.

Is there also a way to introduce reinforced learning (Q-learning) to improve the simulation?

Sincerly,
Victor

Do I need to create a new function that updates pollution when population increased?

```
Below is the example code:

breed [ people person ]
breed [ trees tree ]

turtles-own [ health ]

patches-own [
  pollution
  is-power-plant?
]

to setup
  clear-all

  set-default-shape people "person"
  set-default-shape trees "tree"

  ask patches [
    set pollution 0
    set is-power-plant? false
  ]

  create-power-plants

  ask patches [ pollute ]

  create-people initial-population [
    set color black
    setxy random-pxcor random-pycor
    set health 5
  ]

  reset-ticks
end

to go

  if not any? people [ stop ]

  ask people [
    wander
    reproduce
    maybe-plant
    eat-pollution
    maybe-die
  ]

  diffuse pollution 0.8

  ask patches [ pollute ]

  ask trees [
    cleanup
    maybe-die
  ]

  tick
end

to create-power-plants
  ask n-of power-plants patches [
    set is-power-plant? true
  ]
end

to pollute  ;; patch procedure
  if is-power-plant? [
    set pcolor red
    set pollution polluting-rate
  ]
  set pcolor scale-color red (pollution - .1) 5 0
end

to cleanup  ;; tree procedure
  set pcolor green + 3
  set pollution max (list 0 (pollution - 1))
  ask neighbors [
    set pollution max (list 0 (pollution - .5))
  ]
  set health health - 0.1
end

to wander  ;; person procedure
  rt random-float 50
  lt random-float 50
  fd 1
  set health health - 0.1
end

to reproduce  ;; person procedure
  if health > 4 and random-float 1 < birth-rate [
    hatch-people 1 [
      set health 5
    ]
  ]
end

to maybe-plant  ;; person procedure
  if random-float 1 < planting-rate [
    hatch-trees 1 [
      set health 5
      set color green
    ]
  ]
end

to eat-pollution  ;; person procedure
  if pollution > 0.5 [
    set health (health - (pollution / 10))
  ]
end

to maybe-die  ;; die if you run out of health
  if health <= 0 [ die ]
end


; Copyright 2007 Uri Wilensky.
; See Info tab for full copyright and license.
```

Comment: This will probably be closed as "too broad". How Stack Overflow works is, you're expected to ask only one question at a time, and the question must be about specific code you are writing.